# Interface needed to access overridden abstract property in classes derived from generic abstract base?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface, abstract-class

So my dilemma is that in order to access `IntThing`'s or `StringThing`'s `MyProperty` from `UtilityThing<T>`, I'm defining an interface with `MyProperty` and using it as the generic constraint on `T` in `UtilityThing<T>`.  This is working, but seems redundant given that the same property is already defined in the abstract base.  Am I missing a facet of design here, or is this actually the way it needs to be done in this instance?

```
public interface IThing {
    string MyProperty { get; set; } 
}

public abstract class Thing<T> {
    protected string _MyProperty;
    public abstract string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public T OtherProperty { get; set; }

    public string CommonMethod() {
        return MyProperty + "foobar";   
    }
}

public class IntThing : Thing<int?>, IThing {
    public override string MyProperty {
        get { return _MyProperty; }
        set { _MyProperty = value + OtherProperty.ToString(); }
    }
}

public class StringThing: Thing<string>, IThing {
    public override string MyProperty {
        get { return _MyProperty; }
        set { _MyProperty = OtherProperty + value; }
    }
}

public class UtilityThing<T> where T: IThing, new() {
    public T DoIt(SomeContext someContext, string name) {
        string contextVal = someContext.GetValue(name);

        var thing = new T { MyProperty = contextVal }
        return thing;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer )

Comment: The usual approach would be to introduce another abstract class `Thing` which contains the non-generic-requiring members of `Thing<T>` and then have `Thing<T>` derive from `Thing`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever which members would you move though? MyProperty implementation is dependent on OtherProperty ;), and I want it to stay abstract so that its implementation is required by deriving classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to introduce a new generic type. Once the new type is introduced you can eliminate the need of the interface.

```
public class UtilityThing<T, I> where T : Thing<I>, new()
{
    public T DoIt(SomeContext someContext, string name)
    {
        string contextVal = someContext.GetValue(name);

        var thing = new T { MyProperty = contextVal };
        return thing;
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
var utility = new UtilityThing<IntThing, int?>();
```

Comment: But `Thing<T>` is abstract, can't be instantiated.

Comment: @BrettRossier You're not instantiating the abstract class, you're instantiating the concrete IntThing or StringThing, you're just saying T must derive from your abstract class. I've edited my response

Comment: Hmm, that works, but that essentially moves the redundancy into `UtilityThing`'s generic arguments.  Also, the original usage portion of your example would have failed because of lack of convertibility of `IntThing` to `Thing<int>` (`IntThing` is a `Thing<int?>`, not `Thing<int>`).  I'd like to avoid that sort of usage gotcha, although it would be caught at compile-time.

Comment: It'd be nice if C# did a bit more type inference based on constraints.  `UtilityThing<IntThing>` would infer the type needed in the constraint `where T: Thing<I>`

Comment: @BrettRossier - type inference is already one of the most complex parts of the compiler, sometimes leading to exponential complexity. To simplify the implementation, they decided that inference would be all-or-nothing. If you want to specify one type, you have to specify all. Of course, for classes (rather than methods) which don't also provide a companion non-generic factory class, you have no inference at all.